# Intersect command is not working

Tags: mysql, lampp

```
MariaDB [object]> select Protein, count(mirna) from exp2 
INTERSECT select Protein, count(mirna) from exp3 group by Protein;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'select Protein, count(mirna) from exp3 group by
>   Protein' at line 1.

I have two tables exp2 and exp3, both have many common rows, I want to query from the common data from these two tables.i.e. I want have a common data table of Protein and corresponding count of miRNAs in number.

I am using lampp, how I can resolve this query?

Comment: thanks for editing the format of question.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't offer the `INTERSECT` operation.  You need to use something like a JOIN operation. This example suppresses all rows that don't match the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT a.Protein, a.mirnacount
  FROM (SELECT Protein, count(mirna) mirnacount from exp2 group by Protein) a
  JOIN (SELECT Protein, count(mirna) mirnacount from exp3 group by Protein) b
    ON a.Protein = b.Protein AND a.mirnacount = b.mirnacount
```

You might consider switching to PostgreSQL if a full complement of set operations are needed for your project.

Comment: it return an empty set

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT  T1.Protein,count(T1.miRNAID)`
`FROM exp2 AS T1`
`INNER JOIN exp3 AS T2` 
`ON T1.Protein = T2.Protein` 
`AND T1.Target_Protein_id= T2.Target_Protein_id` 
`AND T1.miRNAID=T2.miRNAID`
`GROUP BY  T1.Protein` 
`ORDER BY count(T1.miRNAID)`

this works perfectly for me.